# problem of replaceAll()

Tags: java

I have written the following line of code:

```
str.replaceAll("xxx(ayyy)xxx", "$1".substring(0,1).equals("a") ? "a" : "b");
```

But I found that "$1".substring(0,1) will output "$" instead of "a". Is that any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Call me crazy, but what exactly is `$1` there for? I don't see how this is relevant to whats going on.

Comment: I gather $1 is supposed to represent the group matched (ayyy) but Slaks has alredy said why that won't work. @Alan, try to tell us _what_ you want to do rather than _how_ you're trying to do it. There's almost always a better way :-)

Comment: @Anthony: It's supposed to match the first capture group from the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `replaceAll` is a regular string.

Java will evaluate your parameter before passing it to the function, not for each match.
`"$1".substring(0,1)` simply returns the first character in the string `$1`.

You need to call the [`appendReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `Matcher` class in a loop.

Comment: Good catch, @Slaks, I gather OP is trying to replace 'xxxNyyyxxx' with 'a' when N=='a' or 'b' when N!='a'. But since it's _always_ 'a', they might as well just replace 'xxxayyyxxx' with 'a' and not fiddle around with groups.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I assume that that's only an example, and that he isn't replacing a hard-coded string.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear explaination! I know what to do now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply different replacements for each match, use `appendReplacement`/`appendTail`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xxx(ayyy)xxx");
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher("...");
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(out, m.group(1).substring(0, 1).equals("a") ? "a" : "b");
}
m.appendTail(out);
```

Answer (score -2):

substring(start, end) will get you a substring from start till one before end. If you want to eliminate the first element try substring(1,lengthOfString)

Comment: He realizes that; that's not his problem.